# SQLite ORDER BY DATE after importing .csv file

Tags: sqlite, csv

My issue is quite weird, because it won't order my query result by its date field.. This is what I had done so far:

I create a table with schema below:

```
    CREATE TABLE temp_price_list (
        kode TEXT,
        nama TEXT,
        merk TEXT,
        jenis TEXT,
        modal TEXT,
        tanggal DATE,
        keterangan TEXT);
```

Below are my csv data:

```
44O2-24V,SEAL-BEAM,KOITO-II,UNIVERSAL,OL3-10,2010/12/17,OCU2-201
4401-24V,SEAL-BEAM,KOITO-II,UNIVERSAL,OL3-10,2010/10/15,OCU2-201
4401-24V,SEAL-BEAM,KYOTO,BULAT-KECIL-2COP,,2010/03/31,OL311
4402-24V,SEAL-BEAM,KYOTO,BULAT-KECIL-3COP,,2013/02/06,OLU2-IO
4402-24V,SEAL-BEAM,GEN,UNIVERSAL,,2014/04/30,IEU219
"H4-7""SEGI",SEAL-BEAM,GEN JP,UNIVERSAL,,2010/04/30,IEU211
7010-BLAT,SEAL-BEAM,RRT,12V=3COP=75W,CWU2-IO,2013/02/06,IWU2=24
7010-BLAT,SEAL-BEAM,DEPO,12V=3COP=75W,SOU222=PC,2012/01/07,IWU2=24
6014-12V,SEAL-BEAM,KYOTO,BULAT   BIG   7010-12V   3C0P,OAU2-201,2010/08/10,OEU2-10
6052-12V,SEAL-BEAM,KYOTO,SEGI    BESAR   3-COP,CFU2-IO,2013/02/06,CSU2-10
4402-24V,SEAL-BEAM,GEN,UNIVERSAL,CEU2-22,2010/05/26,IU311
4401-24V,SEAL-BEAM,GEN,UNIVERSAL  =34=CO3,CEU2-22,2010/06/30,IU311
4001-12V,SEAL-BEAM,AIKOH,UNIVERSAL,,2010/09/17,XOU229
4002-12V,SEAL-BEAM,KYOTORRT,UNIVERSAL,,2013/02/06,OLU2-IO
4002-12V,SEAL-BEAM,GEN,UNIVERSAL,,2011/04/16,CSU222
33365-87701,SYNCROMES-KEY,SB,S-75   SMALL,,2012/01/25,O3-10
33365-87503,SYNCROMES-KEY,SB,S-75   BIG,,2012/01/25,OLRT-10
33365-87503,SYNCROMES-KEY,GB,S-75   BIG,,2012/01/25,I3-11
9-33263-048-1,SYNCROMES-KEY,GTYPE,PTER  3/4,,2010/05/31,F311
8-94152-557-0,SYNCROMES-KEY,G-TYPE,PTER 1/2,,2010/03/31,F311
```

Then I import those data using below command:

```
.mode csv
.import C:/sqlite/test.csv temp_price_list
```

Then I'll try to fetch the data using below query:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_price_list ORDER BY DATE(tanggal) DESC;
```

However it doesn't order it by date, just as the same ordering as the input. Any idea guys ?
I'm stuck here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason -** The Date information in your table is not in the correct format.

**How to solve**

Before inserting the data in your date column, convert the data into one of the standard date formats

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

as mentioned in the below link. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

when you want to insert date to database, you can use this code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

In database insert the string 'date'

Comment: Ahh. I already read about that, I didn't realize that I'm still using "/". I think I need to take some rest. Hahaha. Lemme try first though.

Comment: @user26409021, Good ... May be you can try what i have suggested later and if it works. Mark it as answer and close the loop.